# Unable to start service of Tomcat 7 on Windows 7

Tags: apache, tomcat

I have downloaded Apache tomcat 7 on my laptop.
I run the start up.bat file. Then I check on localhost:8080 and I get that Apache tomcat is successfully running.
Now, I want to start its service, but when I go to services.msc and run Tomcat, it does not run. Moreover, On the command prompt when I do " service.bat install", the result fails.
I actually want to start the service of tomcat. 
What should I do ?? Can anyone please guide me, I checked many websites, but the steps are not much clear.

First, I tried with: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html

But unable to do it.

Comment: What error do you get? Do you run the command line as an administrator when you execute service.bat?

Answer (score 1):

Download the installer .exe file for Tomcat7 in-order to install and run the Tomcat7(32-bit/64-bit Windows Service Installer (pgp, md5, sha1)).

Do not download the Zip file of Tomcat7